# Intellij toolwindow close/open or show/hide programatically

Tags: intellij-idea, visibility, show-hide

I have used the Intellij's tool window as the main frame. On click of a button from the same window, another window (jdialog) opens. When the jDialog box opens, i want to hide or close the tool window. And when the user clicks the stop button in the jDialog box, I want the tool window to appear again.

I have tried to set the visible property to false, like

`toolWindow.getComponent().setVisible(false);`

This just hides the content, but not the tool window itself.
Can you please suggest me a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you show/active it:

`toolWindow.activate(null);`

so hide could be like this:

`toolWindow.hide(null);`

and close like this:

`ContentManager contentManager = toolWindow.getContentManager();
contentManager.removeAllContents(true);
contentManager.dispose();`

(but I have not tried it :))